# SQL Server INSERT INTO OUTPUT Inserted.ID creates mutliple rows (should be one)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba, excel, sql-insert

I have an Excel front-end on a SQL Server 2008 back-end (using VBA to connect the two). When I try and get the ID of an inserted row (using `OUTPUT Inserted.ID`), the SQL statement that VBA sends to the database results in 6 rows being created (not one row). If I execute the SQL statement in SSMS, it only creates a single row (as it should).

Here is the VBA function:

```
Public Function AddHeadline(ByRef strHeadline As String) As Long

Dim lngID As Long

'Does the Headline already exist?
lngID = GetHeadlineID(strHeadline)

If lngID = 0 Then 'No it doesn't, so create it
    mstrSQL = "INSERT INTO Dashboard.Headlines (Headline) OUTPUT Inserted.HeadlineID " & _
              "VALUES('" & FormatForSQL(strHeadline) & "')"
    lngID = GetDatabaseValueAsLong(mstrSQL, mcn)

End If

AddHeadline = lngID

End Function
```

And here are the resulting 6 rows created in SQL Server:

```
(HeadlineID, Headline, TimeAdded)

(-2147482161, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.285483912)
(-2147482164, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.2854837191)
(-2147482163, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.2854837191)
(-2147482162, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.2854837191)
(-2147482166, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.2854836805)
(-2147482165, The status of 'P42M US' changed to 'Future' on 19/02/2014, 41687.2854836805)
```

FYI, `TimeAdded` is Excel format. All 6 rows convert back to `'17/02/2014  06:51:06'` i.e. they are less than a second apart.

There are no triggers on the table.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

David

Comment: What does variable `strHeadline` contain?

Comment: It looks to me like `GetHeadlineID` is not working correctly, and repeated calls to `AddHeadline` won't find an existing entry.

Comment: strheadline contains a string that represents the Headline text. Thanks marcw, but the GetHeadlineID function just runs a SELECT statement against the table to see if a headline with that text already exists:

    'Public Function GetHeadlineID(ByRef strHeadline As String) As Long
    
        strHeadline = Left$(strHeadline, 512)
    
        mstrSQL = "SELECT HeadlineID " & _
              "FROM Dashboard.Headlines " & _
              "WHERE Headline='" & FormatForSQL(strHeadline) & "'"

        GetHeadlineID = GetDatabaseValueAsLong(mstrSQL, mcn)

    End Function'